# Are all virtualization (OS/above-OS) utilities DevOps utilities?

Tags: terminology, virtualization

Are all virtualization (OS/above-OS) utilities commonly considered DevOps utilities?

These could be *OS virtalization* utilities like VirtualBox and Vagrant and maybe also WSL is considered as such and also, *above OS virtualization* tools like docker (AFAIK CMs like Ansible, Chef, Puppet and so forth aren't meant for "virtuallizing" anythin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you have touched another, far more fundamental question - what makes a utility a "DevOps" one? That is, how do you measure the "DevOpsness" of a tool and formalize facts in this context?

Possibly, my wish list for DevOpsness of a tool, **virtualization tools** or other, if they fulfill further criteria down on this list:

- Open and interoperable API, both for operational and intelligence needs
- Optimized workflows, see "developer experience"
- Machine readable configuration as code
- User community
- Short release cycles
- Certificate of software quality which is nowadays yet very ambigous

Comment: I guess we can sum it up and say that a sysadmin (most likely for Linux), with an expertise in virtualization tools === DevOp.